# Ubuntu One + Android - sync any file?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, android

I recently started playing Baldur's Gate again, and since I have a decent Android phone and lots of time to kill while commuting, I thought it'd be cool to sync the saves on my laptop with my phone so I can continue playing.

Any ideas as how to do that? (Not neccessarily via Ubuntu One, if there are other/better alternatives...)

Answer (score 2):

Are you aware of the Ubuntu One Files app for Android? [You can find it here.](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ubuntuone.android.files)

Although you might be able to get One to automatically sync your pc's Baldur's Gate files, it will require manual downloading and uploading on your phone.

I cannot think of other cloud solutions more suitable to this task, unfortunately.